# error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown' in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

hello i need help to resolve this error

```
try{

} catch {
  let errMsg;
  if (error.code === 11000) {
    errMsg = Object.keys(error.keyValue)[0] + "Already exists";
  }
  return res.status(500).json({ msg: errMsg });
}

console.log(error);
```

=>error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'

Comment: This looks like a typo-level error. You don't have a binding on the `catch`, you just have `catch { /*...*/ }`, not (for instance) `catch (error: any) { /* ... */ }`. While that's valid as of relatively recently, it means that you aren't creating an `error` binding with the `try`/`catch`, which you probably meant to. (Sadly, the type annotation on a `catch` binding is required to be either `any` or `unknown`, and if you want to use `error.code`, you'll have to use `any`.)

Comment: Also `error.code`, there is no code on the default `Error` object, if you have a custom error class, you will also need a type guard for this.  eg.   `if (error instanceof IOError) {}`.. etc.  Actually even for `Error` you need a type guard :(,  this is because in JS its possible to throw anything, even `throw 7` is valid..

Answer (score 4):

You can set [useUnknownInCatchVariables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useUnknownInCatchVariables) as `false` in `tsconfig.json`.

```
try {

} catch(err) { // the type of catch variable is any

}
```

But use `any` is not a safe way, handle all possible boundary conditions manually  is much better.

```
catch(err: unknown) {
  if (err instanceof Error) { // narrow `err` from `unknown` to `Error`
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```